# Go to Base in resharper 5?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Since i have installed R# 5 i found that "Go To Base" has disappeared from context menu. Does any alternatives? , because now when i need to see the code of the base method or property i have to go to base class and find this method/property manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click -> Navigate to -> Base symbols
(shortcut says Ctrl + U)

Answer (score 0):

There is a small icon in the left margin for every overloaded function (looks like a arrow next to a blue circle), click it to go to the definition.